# VB.Net calling win32 api on 32 and 64 bit systems, runs OK on 32 but not 64

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi, named-pipes

To make an existing managed application with unmanaged 'appendages' 64-bit capable, I decided to rewrite a 32 bit unmanaged VC++ dll as a managed VB.Net class library.

The application must be able to run on any framework from 2.0 up, and the VC++ code I ported was using named pipes, which are supported only from framework 3.5 up.
So I had to resort to reflection, calling windows API functions for everything related to the pipes.

The result works perfectly in 32 bit mode, but in 64 bit, I get all kinds of trouble. The actual behavior may change dramatically with even the least change in source code, just swapping some variable declarations around or moving a simple assignment statement to another location in the code may cause any effect from

- "a barely noticeable hiccup every X hours of running fine",
- "appear to receive some bad data from time to time" (it actually took WireShark and a decent portion of luck to find out that the first byte of a 13-byte packet received on the named pipe was passed as 0x00 to managed code, while it was actually received as 0x02 in the pipe data packet, while the rest of the packet was passed intact)

to

- "crash the entire .Net runtime with an error 0xc0000409 in mscorwks.dll soon as a client tries to connect to the pipe".

If you ask me, the quick change in symptoms, but especially the latter, points towards something somewhere, probably a pointer or handle, that is still being stored or passed to/from Win32 API at 32 bit sizes when running at 64 bit. But I don't succeed in figuring out what.

The most likely location is in the API declarations. The rest is all managed code, and compiled with options 'strict' and 'explicit' both on.
Can someone have a look at the snippets below and see if he can spot something I keep overlooking?

Operation is asynchonous. The actual waits are performed at managed level on an array containing managed as well as unmanaged handles (through SafeWaitHandle wrapping), so events in managed together with unmanaged stuff can be dealt with by a single WaitHandle.WaitAny(...array...) call.

```
<DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function CreateNamedPipe(
    lpName As String,
    dwOpenMode As Int32,
    dwPipeMode As Int32,
    nMaxInstances As Int32,
    nOutBufferSize As Int32,
    nInBufferSize As Int32,
    nDefaultTimeOut As Int32,
    lpSecurityAttributes As IntPtr    ' when declared as SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES runtime won't accept passing Nothing, even when marked <[Optional]>
) As Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle : End Function

<DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function ConnectNamedPipe(
    hNamedPipe As SafeHandle,
    ByRef lpOverlapped As System.Threading.NativeOverlapped
) As Boolean : End Function

<DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function DisconnectNamedPipe(
    ByVal hNamedPipe As SafeHandle
) As Boolean : End Function

<DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function ReadFile(
    <[In]> hFile As SafeHandle,
    <Out> lpBuffer As IntPtr,
    <[In]> nNumberOfBytesToRead As Int32,
    <Out, [Optional]> ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As Int32,
    <[In], Out, [Optional]> ByRef lpOverlapped As System.Threading.NativeOverlapped
) As Boolean : End Function

<DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function WriteFile(
    <[In]> hFile As SafeHandle,
    <[In]> lpBuffer As IntPtr,
    <[In]> nNumberOfBytesToWrite As Int32,
    <[Out], [Optional]> ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Int32,
    <[In], [Out], [Optional]> ByRef lpOverlapped As NativeOverlapped
) As Boolean : End Function

<DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function CloseHandle(hHandle As SafeHandle) As Boolean : End Function

<DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function CloseHandle(hHandle As IntPtr) As Boolean : End Function

<DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function GetOverlappedResult(
    ByVal hFile As SafeHandle,
    ByRef lpOverlapped As System.Threading.NativeOverlapped,
    ByRef lpNumberOfBytesTransferred As Int32,
    ByVal bWait As Boolean
) As Boolean : End Function

<DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function CancelIo(
    <[In]> hFile As SafeHandle
) As Boolean : End Function

<DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function PeekNamedPipe(
    <[In]> hNamedPipe As SafeHandle,
    <Out, [Optional]> ByRef lpBuffer As Byte(),
    <[In]> nBufferSize As Integer,
    <Out, [Optional]> ByRef lpBytesRead As Integer,
    <Out, [Optional]> ByRef lpTotalBytesAvail As Integer,
    <Out, [Optional]> ByRef lpBytesLeftThisMessage As Integer
) As Boolean : End Function

<DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function GetProcessHeap() As IntPtr : End Function

<DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function HeapAlloc(
    <[In]> hHeap As IntPtr,
    <[In]> dwFlags As Int32,
    <[In]> dwBytes As IntPtr
) As IntPtr : End Function

<DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function HeapFree(
    <[In]> hHeap As IntPtr,
    <[In]> dwFlags As Int32,
    <[In]> lpMem As IntPtr
) As Boolean : End Function

<DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function CreateEvent(
    <[In], [Optional]> lpEventAttributes As IntPtr,
    <[In]> bManualReset As Boolean,
    <[In]> bInitialState As Boolean,
    <[In], [Optional]> lpName As String
) As IntPtr : End Function
```

This is how CreateEvent is used to create a handle managed code can wait for:

```
Private Shared Function AllocateEventHandle() As Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle
    Return New Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle(CreateEvent(Nothing, False, False, Nothing), True)
End Function
```

Buffers to be used in calls to unmanaged code are created like this:

```
Private Shared Function AllocateBuffer(nBytes As Integer) As IntPtr
    Return HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, New IntPtr(nBytes))
End Function
```

Comment: Defect in your code. We can't see your code. You can. Debug your code

Comment: `Out` attribute on `ReadFile`'s second parameter looks wrong.  Even worse on `PeekNamedPipe`.

Comment: Also, I don't think you know what "reflection" means.  p/invoke is not reflection.

Comment: That 'out' parameter on ReadFile's second parameter comes straight from the Win32 API documentation on MSDN. The same for PeekNamedPipe. But you're right about reflection and p/invoke, I tend to mix up those terms.

Comment: And I did it again, mixing up terms. Please s/parameter/attribute/ in previous comment.

Comment: The declarations might or might not be wrong, but judging from existence of `Function CloseHandle(hHandle As SafeHandle)` the main problem might be in how you create and use pipe and wait handles.

Comment: `[out]` in MSDN C++ API declarations and the .Net's `OutAttribute` are very different Outs. The MSDN one tells you that you provide the buffer address, but the API fills the buffer. The .Net one declares that the API returns the address of the buffer. You would achieve the same meaning on the .Net side by declaring e.g. `<Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)> lpBuffer As Byte()`.

Comment: The `_Out_` attribute for [ReadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467.aspx) is an SAL annotation for static code analyzers. It has different semantics from the `<Out>` attribute in your P/Invoke signature. This is a bug.

Comment: Targeting a 12 year version of free software that hasn't been supported for over half a decade is quite nonsensical.  Surely you wasted enough energy on this already, no point in extending the agony to other users here.  Use the System.IO.Pipes namespace.

Comment: @Hans: I would agree, if it were public software. Let the customers pay for the OS upgrades. But this is internal software, and upgrading to a framework that contains System.IO.Pipes would cost more (in hardware replacement, installation and license cost) than paying my salary from today up to my pension.

Comment: That is nonsense as well, it does not require an "OS upgrade".  There is no machine left that did not get auto-updated to 3.5 SP1 by Windows Update.

Comment: @Hans: not nonsense. The targets are embedded devices on a private network without a gateway to the internet, no automatic updates (and again: no internet access, neither in nor out, in case someone would start screaming in panic now). Different models of hardware, running different OS versions, but all the same application software. The oldest ate running XP Embedded SP2 on a mainboard that would melt if you tried to run Windows 7 on it.

Comment: Time to learn how to debug then. And to listen to answers when you ask for help.

Comment: @David - don't think I didn't listen to the answers. And as for debugging, the problem is that the code runs flawlessly on my development machine (Windows 10 64 bit) and on two test platforms. It only started acting up on a third system that was being prepared for a pilot roll-out. That is when I discovered that it just isn't something that's easy to debug.  Sometimes, when it happens, the entire process just disappears when it's deep in the core DLL. Sometimes everything looks like it's right, but the data you receive from unmanaged code isn't the data that was sent to you by that code.

Comment: And thanks to the people who actually could tell me where my code contained errors, and why. BTW, I made a small mistake in one of my comments: the oldest devices aren't running XP Embedded, there are still a few left that are based on Windows 2000. The hardware must be at least 15 years old, but we're stuck with people on the top floor who can't be convinced that it sometimes pays to replace something before it breaks (and to their credit: if one in 1000 breaks, the other 999 keep working and will even compensate for the broken one, it's no financial drain to have a small percentage down).

Comment: BTW, even though flaws in my declarations were pointed out, I still don't have an explanation for the fact that it only affects 64 bit execution. I created a build targeted at x86, and that build runs perfectly everywhere. It's just the AnyCpu targeted build that shows the symptoms.

Comment: I tried to fix the [in] and [out] attributes. x86 build still runs as before, 64 bit still doesn't. So I think I'll have to turn back to my original search: where did I leave something stuk in 32 bit mode that makes execution on x64 go down in flames.  Thanks for your help, to all those who tried.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why it would make any difference between 32 and 64 bit, but this seems to be what was haunting me:

All over the .Net documentation, you read that this or that object type is thread-safe as long as it is static (VB shared) - so much that I silently started to believe it was true for all object types. I *especially* expected it to be true for things that are commonly, almost typically used in multi-threaded processing, such as event handles.

It appears that this is not always true for 64 bit code.

To recap: 32 bit builds of my project always ran as they should, AnyCpu builds on 64 bit systems did not.

For the named pipe handling (creation, connection, and I/O), I allocated win32 event handles and buffers through API calls. The event handles were wrapped in SafeWaitHandles for managed use, buffers were just being pointed to by IntPtr on the managed side.

Because these handles and buffers were created only once at application startup and never needed to be released or replaced during execution, I allocated them as soon as I could, from within the application's main startup thread.
They would later be *used* by another thread, that may be started and stopped multiple times over the process' lifetime.

What I did now, more by way of experiment than out of wisdom, was move the creation of those handles and buffers into the thread that would use them (and release them at thread exit).

The problem went away as if it never existed, 32 and 64 bit runs are both perfectly stable now.

Comment: This bears no relation to the question that was asked. It also appears to be largely made up.

Comment: @David. Made up? Definitely not.Correct? I don't know, I'm just trying to explain what I see happening, without fully understanding why it happens. So if you have a better idea, your contribution is welcome.

Comment: As it is, I don't really believe this really is the answer either. If there is one thing I've learned in 40 years (Stroustrup was still breeding on C++ when I was writing and debugging C code, thank you for the suggestion to learn how to debug), it is that if you change something and it seems to work, but you can't really put your finger on the bug and squash it, it probably means that it has just crawled away and will bite you somewhere else tomorrow. And this kind of thing IS not easy to debug, because the symptoms you see may be a mile removed from the problem.